# How to throw error when String is not matched with element

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java

I'm trying to click an element from list elements where link element equal to String. I need to verify that error will throw if they're not equal.

It works when the String I am comparing is matched with the element using if statement. I'm getting an error once I put a condition in else statement. It somehow lists the whole elements

```java
public void clickFromList(By element, String item) throws Exception{
    try {
        List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(element);
        for (WebElement webElement : linkElements) {
            String eleText = webElement.getText();
            if(eleText.matches(item)) {
                System.out.println("Selected: " + eleText);
                webElement.click();
                System.out.println("Clicked: " + eleText);
                break;
            }else {
                 Assert.assertFalse(true, "Error");
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
          Assert.fail("Can't find the element in the page. The element is: " +element);
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Error expected [false] but found [true]
```

Comment: if you want your method to throw an error, throw an Exception, don't use Assertions.

Comment: hi @Stultuske, i tried it. it is failing my if statement as only capturing the first element. does it require to add elements into arraylist?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. as soon as your iteration encounters a value that is not equal, it will throw that error, it would be better to just keep a flag (boolean) which you update during the iteration, and check that value after the iteration finishes.

Comment: Hi, I added an Boolean and it worked. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below given code, let me know if it works for you.

```
public void clickFromList(By element, String item) throws Exception{
try {
    List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(element);
    for (WebElement webElement : linkElements) {
        String eleText = webElement.getText();
        if(eleText.matches(item)) {
            System.out.println("Selected: " + eleText);
            webElement.click();
            System.out.println("Clicked: " + eleText);
            break;
        }
 else 
 {
 //in assert false method string comes first
 Assert.assertFalse("Element not found with the given text in list",false);
        }
    }
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      Assert.fail("Can't find the element in the page. The element is: " +element);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your inputs but i tried this already and it didn't work. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can throw custom exception like below:

```
throw new Exception("Message");
```

Comment: I did that but my if statement is failing as list is only capturing the first element.

Comment: @Vince I explained that in my last comment. Aravinda, this should be a comment, not an answer, since it doesn't actually answer the question